# java error when a variable is inserted inside a json formatted script in jmeter

Tags: java, json, http, jmeter, performance-testing

I have a json script like

```
{  
    "header":{  
      "un":"retail",
      "ut":"1?75d1944c204d140c?-1",
      "appId":[  
         "BFBT"
      ]
    },
```

The 'ut' field is dynamic, so I have a variable named '${utExtractor}' coming from a regular expression which extracts this value (this contains a session value, by the way). Now, a simple insertion of this variable in the script would be something like

```
{  
    "header":{  
      "un":"retail",
      "ut":"${utExtractor}",
      "appId":[  
         "BFBT"
      ]
    },
```

After running this, a java error is found in the server logs. I have no idea why such simple change in the script would product such weird error (Process Not Found). Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Below are the screenshots of the HTTP Sampler and the View Result Tree

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1. from where are you reading JSON? hardcoded? or reading from CSV? 2. did you add JSON in HTTP Sampler Post Body? 3. What is the error shown in jmeter.log, add to the question? share the screenshots. check with debug sample and View Results Tree listenert and see wether the value is captured by RegExExtractor.

Comment: 1. hardcoded (it came from the HTTP Test Script Recorder) 2. No, have no idea how that works. 3. The error is 'Process Not Found'

Comment: your requests seem working properly. ALL GREEN & values are replaced correctly in the request and got the successful response. I am not sure what error you are talking about. can you share the error shown in the log file? execution perspective, everything is good.

Comment: yes,, all are working properly except the fact that they are not inserted into the database because of that error. and it's weird because i only get that whenever i insert a variable in the json script

Comment: Is it server logs? Are you sure data is inserted when you use hardcoded JSON?

Comment: Yes, it is server logs. Yes, if I don't use a variable, the data is inserted. But the thing is, I will have session error issues so I will have to make it a dynamic variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128418/discussion-between-naveen-and-harold-decapia).

Comment: you have question marks in that token. You may need to url encode them before sending in POST